# Lost access to my account, "No OpenID endpoint found"

Tags: support, login, duplicate-accounts

This is my user profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/444569/kuttan-sujith

I had many important questions there, but I lost my username. My OpenID is `sujithukvl.myopenid.com`, but it says "No OpenID endpoint found."

Can any one help me to find out how I was logging in before

Comment: MyOpenId shut down about 8 months ago. See [myOpenID shuts down February 1, 2014; add an alternative login method to your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442)

Comment: Also see [Missed the MyOpenID demise; account lost forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235192)